# Redirect Console Output ,Terminal (macOS, CentOS) / Cmd (Windows) to Remote Syslog or Server Logs

Tags: logging, syslog, terminal, windows-command-prompt, listener

I have One workstation running multiple instances of Java applications by Console/Terminal for Testing, and I develop an application for Listening Logs, TCP like (http://esus.com/using-java-util-logging-sockethandler/) and UDP like (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-udp-datagramsockets-java/)

I need to send the output of each applications to respective tester (with my for Listening Logs)

I have a Server for UDP listening on 514 port, and for TCP listening on 5000 port. Suposse the Ip server, 192.168.0.100

I want to do some like:

*(CentOS/macOS)*

```
$ [java -jar | mvn | WhateverCommand] | CommandSender 192.168.0.100 [514|5000]
```

*(Windows)*

```
C:\> [java -jar | mvn | WhateverCommand] | CommandSender 192.168.0.100 [514|5000]
```